# Approximation of a polymorphic local variable

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, local-variables

I would like to make the runtime type of a local variable depend on some condition. Say we have this situation:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base{ 
public:
    virtual void foo()=0; 
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
    virtual void foo(){
        std::cout << "D1" << std::endl;
    }
};
class Derived2 : public Base {
    virtual void foo(){
        std::cout << "D2" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

In Java-like languages where objects are always handled through "references" the solution is simple (pseudocode):

```
Base x = condition ? Derived1() : Derived2();
```

The C++ solution will obviously involve pointers (at least behind the scenes), since there is no other way to bring two different types under the same variable (which must have a type). It cannot be simply `Base` as `Base` objects cannot be constructed (it has a pure virtual function).

The simplest way would be to use raw pointers:

```
Base* x = condition ? static_cast<Base*>(new Derived1()) : static_cast<Base*>(new Derived2());
```

(The casts are needed to make the two branches of the ternary operator have the same type)

Manual pointer handling is error-prone and old school, this situation calls for a `unique_ptr`.

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> x{condition ? static_cast<Base*>(new Derived1()) : static_cast<Base*>(new Derived2())};
```

Eh... Not exactly what I'd call elegant. It uses explicit new and casting. I hoped to use something like `std::make_unique` to hide the `new` but it doesn't seem possible.

Is this just one of those situations where you conclude "C++ is like that, if you need elegance use other languages (perhaps making a trade-off on other aspects)"?

Or is this whole idea just totally un-C++-ish? Am I in the wrong mindset here, trying to force ideas from different languages on C++?

Comment: "The casts are needed to make the two branches of the ternary operator have the same type" Casting only one of them to the base class should be enough for the compiler to deduce the expression type. A bit less clutter in the code, therefore.

Comment: This looks like an abstract factory; so why don't you separate the surrounding code from the creation of that object? A simple function like `unique_ptr<Base> createDerived(bool const condition) { if(condition) return make_unique<Derived1>(); else return make_unique<Derived2>(); }` also works around the problem by not using a ternary operator.

Comment: `Base` needs a virtual destructor if you are going to do `unique_ptr<Base>`.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this just one of those situations where you conclude "C++ is like that, if you need elegance use other languages (perhaps making a trade-off on other aspects)"?
>
> Or is this whole idea just totally un-C++-ish? Am I in the wrong mindset here, trying to force ideas from different languages on C++?

It really depends on what you are going to use `x` for.

### Variants

> The C++ solution will obviously involve pointers (at least behind the scenes), since there is no other way to bring two different types under the same variable (which must have a type).

You can also use [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/variant.html) (or `boost::any`, but `boost::variant` might be better in this case). For example, given that `Derived1` is default constructible:

```
boost::variant<Derived1, Derived2> x;
if (!condition) x = Derived2();
```

This will work even if `Derived1` and `Derived2` don't share a base class. Then you can use the visitor pattern to operate on `x`. Given, for example:

```
struct Derived1 {
    void foo1(){
        std::cout << "D1" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Derived2 {
    void foo2(){
        std::cout << "D2" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

then you can define the visitor as:

```
class some_visitor : public boost::static_visitor<void> {
public:
    void operator()(Derived1& x) const {
        x.foo1();
    }
    
    void operator()(Derived2& x) const {
        x.foo2();
    }
};
```

and use it as:

```
boost::apply_visitor(some_visitor(), x);
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02c1bb2ad6ad6a86)

### Polymorphic calls

If you really need to use `x` polymorphically, then yes, `std::unique_ptr` is ok. And just call your polymorphic function as `x->foo()`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> x = condition ? std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Derived1()) : std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Derived2());
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b859d1b2871152fb)

### Concepts/Templates

If you just need to call a function than you might just be better off defining a concept and expressing it with templates:

```
template<class Type>
void my_func(Type& x) { x.foo(); }
```

You'll be able to define concepts explicitly in future C++ versions too.

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a687109f3e8b82f)

Answer (score 0):

One 'radical' possibility is to create a new kind of make_unique that will create the right typed return value

```
template<typename TReal, typename TOutside, typename... Args>
auto make_base_unique(Args&&... args) -> std::unique_ptr<TOutside>
{
    return std::unique_ptr<TOutside>(new TReal(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

Then use it like:

```
auto x = (condition ? make_base_unique<Derived1,Base>() : make_base_unique<Derived2,Base>());
```